# Does glycerol in E.coli culture media somehow inhibit the lac-operon?

Tags: biochemistry, proteins, gene-expression, lab-techniques, protein-expression

I have have been taught that one should induce protein expression with IPTG at an OD of about 1.0 - 2.0 when E.coli grows it TB media (terrific broth). As a reference point, one typically induces protein expression at an OD of about 0.5 in the commonly used LB media (Lysogeny/Miller broth). IPTG is a lactose analogue that will induce the expression of proteins encoded in the lac-operon. I have been told that it is important to have a high OD before induction, because the added glycerol in the TB media (5%) will somehow inhibit expression of protein in the lac operon if it is not '*used up*' before induction. **However**, glycerol itself should not inhibit the lac-operon from being transcribed (?).

**I have several speculations about this:** Could it simply be that TB-media has a very long exponential phase (rumoured to support an OD up towards 16.0, personally I routinely reached an OD of 10), and it is therefore not wise to induce protein expression too early (and thus has nothing to do with *using up* up the glycerol)? Another rational explanation that I came across is that glycerol might induce *carbon catabolite repression*, meaning that glycerol might inhibit the uptake of IPTG (or down regulate cAMP levels) and thus indirectly inhibit expression of protein from the lac-operon, but I found it a bit difficult to get a straight answer about this in literature.

Does anyone have some good references for these speculations?

Comment: You can induce as soon as cells go into exponential phase. It is during the lag phase where you should avoid burdening the cells.

Comment: Yes, I was however wondering about the use of glycerol and TB media, i.e. why 'everyone' says to wait for an OD of 1 or more before induction? Are you saying that this is a myth, and it simply does not matter as long as one is in the exponential phase? Or that it simply takes longer to get to the exponential phase in TB media, and thus the recommendation of inducing at a higher OD? I actually haven't document the growth curve in TB-media, I have simply used or modified protokolls, which has worked well for me.

Comment: I cannot provide a conclusive answer here but how soon you induce depends on the load of protein expression. It would vary for different kinds of media. I haven't used TB media, so I can't say much about it. A long-lived protein will reach 90% of steady state concentration within 4 divisions. Based on these factors, you can decide when to do the induction to minimize stress and maximize protein concentration.